# AlertDialog not showing two buttons

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

AlertDialog not showing send button. Below is the code. Please tell me what mistake I have made in my code.

```
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
    final AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    dialog.setMessage("Enter Holla message");
    EditText hollaMessage = new EditText(this);
    dialog.setView(hollaMessage);
    dialog.setCancelable(false);
    dialog.setPositiveButton("Send", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
       public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
          List result = new ArrayList();
       }
    });
    dialog.setPositiveButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            dismissDialog(0);
        }
    });
    AlertDialog alert = dialog.create();
    return alert;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You set the positive button twice.. make it `setNagativeButton("Cancel"`.....

```
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id)
{
    final AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    dialog.setMessage("Enter Holla message");
    EditText hollaMessage = new EditText(this);
    dialog.setView(hollaMessage);
    dialog.setCancelable(false);
    dialog.setPositiveButton("Send", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
            List result = new ArrayList();
        }
    });
    dialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            dismissDialog(0);
        }
    });
    AlertDialog alert = dialog.create();
    return alert;
}
```

Comment: If I want to add 3 buttons, then what I should do ?

Comment: ask this as a seprate question on stackoverflow and accept the answer if it helps you out in this

Comment: I've pretty much done this, but it doesn't work.  Can you help?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15439817/alertdialog-builder-not-displaying-buttons

Answer (score 3):

There is also option of adding neutralbutton. You can add neutral button, as similar to positive and negative button.

Now your next comment would be if I want to add 4 buttons then?

Then simply make the layout in XML of all the four buttons and inflate it to set it on dialog.

[Check this out](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html)

This will solve all your doubts.

Answer (score 0):

add ".show()" end of any button.
for Exam:

```
dialog.setPositiveButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        dismissDialog(0);
    }
}).show();
```

Comment: wrong answer, here you are calling show() method on dialog object, it's not related to that setPositiveButton() method or that button